# Sorting custom object map

Tags: java, android, sorting

I am trying to sort a `HashMap` by  status of `Person`.

I have an object `HashMap<String,Person> persons;` which holds an `Array` and
    `Person` has the fields  `String name`, `add`, `age` and `status`.
I want sort by status. Can I compare the objects or do I have to call `persons.getStatus()`?
Also, which way is better?

I am trying to sort it like this:

```
Collections.sort(person, new Comparator<Person>(){
    public int compare(Person emp1, Person emp2) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What is `Status`? An object, an enum, a String, ??

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` the `compareTo()` method of `Object` and use that.  That's the method that `sort()` calls when it is sorting and uses the return value to decide order.

```
class Person{

 ...

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Person p){
     if (this.status.compareTo(p.getStatus())==0)
     {
       return 0; 
     }

     //Or some numbering system that reflects differing status, anything other than 0 is non-equal
     return -1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: @andro Do you want to extract only the list that has m value or you want those to come first?

Comment: all having m and all having p

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by status this way:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        if (p1.getStatus().m > p2.getStatus().m) {
            return 1;
        } else if (p1.getStatus().m < p2.getStatus().m) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And call your comparator:

```
Collections.sort(person, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: p1. getStatus().contains("p") > p2. getStatus().contains("p")

Comment: its a hashmap<String,person>